# Imap-tools. Mark as 'seen' only messages with attachments

Tags: python, imap-tools

I am using imap-tools to download attachments from unread emails.
I need mark as seen only those messages that contain attachments and have been downloaded.
The code below works, but marks **all** unread messages as seen.

```
import ssl
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND
from datetime import date
context = ssl.create_default_context()
today = date.today()
with MailBox('imap.gmail.com', ssl_context=context).login('email', 'password', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(AND(seen=False), mark_seen = True, bulk = True):
        for att in msg.attachments:
            print(att.filename, today)
            if att.filename.lower().endswith('.xlsx'):
                with open('D:/pp/nf/mail/1.txt', 'a') as f:
                    print(att.filename, today, file=f)
                with open('D:/pp/nf/mail/{}'.format(att.filename), 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(att.payload)
```

Comment: You have `mark_seen=True`; what do you imagine it does?

Comment: I know what `mark_seen=True` does. But I don't know python. Yesterday I read examples of imap-tools on github and wrote this script. My knowledge was not enough for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    seen_msgs = []
    for msg in mailbox.fetch(AND(seen=False), mark_seen = False, bulk = True):
        for att in msg.attachments:
            print(att.filename, today)
            if att.filename.lower().endswith('.xlsx'):
                with open('D:/pp/nf/mail/1.txt', 'a') as f:
                    print(att.filename, today, file=f)
                with open('D:/pp/nf/mail/{}'.format(att.filename), 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(att.payload)
                seen_msgs.append(msg.uid)
    mailbox.flag(seen_msgs, [imap_tools.MailMessageFlags.SEEN], True)
```

Comment: Thanks It works. You just need to add import imap_tools, otherwise we get the error NameError: name 'imap_tools' is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Right answer:

Use fetch arg **mark_seen=False**